# Potentials at terminals of battery connected to ground

Tags: voltage

If we have a battery connected like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXaTL9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Am I correct in thinking  voltage on the positive terminal relative to ground is +9V and on the negative terminal is -9V?

Comment: No, they're both at 0V.

Comment: One shouldn't short the terminals of an ideal battery with an ideal conductor.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Unless one wanted an ideal fire!

Comment: @EnemyOftheStateMachine  Ideal conductor doesn't have resistance.  Ideal battery doesn't have series resistance.  So neither can cause a fire.  But Cthulhu can be summoned by this.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Agreed!  I let the "real life" implications jump over the "ideal life".  0ohms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to build this circuit in real life can cause an electrical fire (depending on exactly how it is connected and the battery's internal state of charge). The wire and battery could get very hot, the insulation around the wire could melt or vaporize as smoke, nearby surfaces could be scorched, and it's even possible that a combustion fire could be triggered.

The **ideal** 9V battery makes a voltage difference of 9V between its (+) and (-) terminals, regardless of where ground is. If the (-) terminal is at ground (0V) then the (+) terminal is at +9V.  If the (+) terminal is at 0V then the (-) terminal is at -9V. If the (-) terminal is at 1000V then the (+) terminal is at 1009V. But it's impossible for the (+) terminal to be +9V while the (-) terminal is at -9V, because then the total (algebraic sum) voltage would be 18V instead of 9V.

A **practical** battery has some internal source resistance distributed throughout the connection terminals, electrodes, and electrolyte -- this can be modeled with a single resistor in series with the ideal voltage source. The lower the battery's internal state of charge, the greater this equivalent internal source resistance becomes.

Real wires also have some non-zero resistance as well as some inductance.

If you click on the "simulate this circuit" link (underneath the schematic picture) you can see the results for yourself. The simulation shows 0V at both ends and 4.5A of current flowing through the loop. (This circuitlab simulator treats a 9V battery as a practical component rather than an ideal voltage source, so the simulator knows there is an upper limit on the current the battery can provide.)

Answer (score 0):

The (+) terminal is +9v relative to the (-) terminal, and the (-) terminal is -9 relative to the (+) terminal.

Using a meter setup for DC voltage, you can see this for yourself.  If you use the black(common/reference) probe on the (-) terminal and the red meter probe on the (+) terminal, the meter will display a positive voltage of around 9v(depending on the state of charge of the battery).

Reverse the probes, and you will get a negative voltage on the meter display.

If you wired the battery as shown (DON'T), the terminals are basically referencing each other, and cancelling each other out...and will create a lot of heat and likely a burning battery/hand/table/house.

If you add a second battery, you can reference a ground between them, and get your +9v and -9v. This was a popular, cheap way to get dual rails for op-amp circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrNyK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>